# I would like to write this code with Reactjs how to do

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to write the code below in Reactjs how to do

```js
@foreach($slide as $item)
  <li data-target="#caImg" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ ($loop->first)? 'active':'' }}"></li>
@endforeach
```

and

```js
@foreach($slide as $item) 
  <div class="carousel-item {{ ($loop->first)? 'active':'' }}"> 
      <src={{$item->image}}/> 
  </div>
@endforeach
```

My code React.js

```js
{
  slides.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <li
        key={value.id}
        data-target="#carouselHomeIndicators"
        data-slide-to={index}
        className={index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: If you are  not looking for a Bug fixes or something its definitely stackoveflow is the right one. So something what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Just use maps

```
{ slide.map((item, idx) =>
    <li data-target="#caImg" data-slide-to={idx} className={idx === 0 ? "active" : ""}></li>
..
```

Similarly with 2nd one.